# Next Palindrome

Tags: python, performance, programming-challenge, palindrome

I've written a function which, given a number string, returns the next largest palindrome in string form. For example, if the input string is `"4738"`, the output should be `"4774"`. The original problem description is found  [here](https://www.codechef.com/problems/PALIN). The function seems to be working for all the tests I have thrown at it so far, but the problem is that it is timing out when I submit it at the website above. Which parts are slow, and how can I improve the performance of this function?

```
# Algorithm: If replacing the right half of the original number with the  
# mirror of the left half results in a bigger number, return that.         
# Otherwise, increment the left half of the number, then replace the   
# right half of the original number with the mirror of the new left half
# and return.

def next_palindrome(n):
    X = len(n)>>1
    Y = X+(len(n)&1)
    first = n[:X][::-1] 
    second = n[Y:] 
    Z = n[:Y]
    if int(first) > int(second): return Z+first
    else: 
        bar = str(int(Z)+1)
        return bar+bar[:X][::-1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your indentation is a little odd. In Python, typically you'd never put two statements on the same line... unless you were [code golfing](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com), in which case you'd probably put all the statements on one single line and/or use 1-space indents.

```
def next_palindrome(n):
    X = len(n)>>1
    Y = X+(len(n)&1)
    first = n[:X][::-1] 
    second = n[Y:] 
    Z = n[:Y]
    if int(first) > int(second):
        return Z+first
    else: 
        bar = str(int(Z)+1)
        return bar+bar[:X][::-1]
```

The biggest time sink here is going to be the line `int(first) > int(second)`, where you're taking two big strings and converting them to integers. That involves a lot of character comparisons and a lot of multiplications by 10... and with the inputs the grader is probably giving you, it'll involve [bignum math](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/538551/handling-very-large-numbers-in-python), which means memory allocation.

You don't actually need to convert the strings to int (or bignum), since you *know* that `first` and `second` are both strings of digits! You can do this instead:

```
assert Y >= X, "by construction"
assert len(second) >= len(first), "by construction"
if len(first) == len(second) && first > second:
    assert int(first) > int(second), "because ASCII"
```

---

I also suspect that

```
first = n[:X][::-1]
```

is not the most efficient way to reverse the first `X` characters of `n` in Python. I would try something like

```
first = n[X-1::-1]
```

But getting rid of the `int`s speeds up your program by a huge factor, so that the above suggestion is completely negligible. I used the following program to benchmark your code:

```
import timeit
setup = '''
    your code
'''
print timeit.timeit('next_palindrome("1234"*10000)', number=1000, setup=setup)
```

Using `int(first) > int(second)`: 4.452 seconds.

Using `X == Y and first > second`: 0.019 seconds.

---

P.S.: Notice that your code ignores leading zeros in both the input and the output. It thinks that the palindrome following `0110` is `22`, not `111`; and the palindrome following `99` is `101`, not `00100`. This is probably fine, but you might enjoy thinking about how to "fix" that issue, too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you explain how ascii comparison works? Also, what happens in the case when int(first) > int(second) but X < Y? In this case do I have to fall back to checking using int() again?

Comment: @SimonZhu: String comparison in Python works by "dictionary order". Digits work just like letters: `"1221" < "312"` in Python for the same reason that `"abba" < "cab"`. (Yes, even though `int("1221") > int("312")`)! As for the second part of your question — I'd advise you to get out a pencil and try to find a case where `int(first) > int(second)` but `len(first) < len(second)`. You'll figure it out on your own. :)